# Vba to copy certain cells to notepad

Tags: excel, vba, notepad

I hope you can help

I need the following vba script to copy the concatenated cells B2 and B4 to a new notepad. Any ideas?

```
A   B
a   (IDNo IN ('a'
b   (IDNo IN ('a', 'b '
c   (IDNo IN ('a', 'b ', 'c'
d   (IDNo IN ('a', 'b ', 'c', 'd'
e   (IDNo IN ('a', 'b ', 'c', 'd', 'e'
```

Code to paste selection into new notepad:

```html
'Start Notepad And let it recieve focus
    Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
    'Send the keys CTRL+V To Notepad (i.e the window that has focus)
    SendKeys "^V"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Adrian! Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a new help field in Sheet2 and exporting results to Notepad